# Strange Javascript Caching in My Asset Pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching

Caching is the only explanation I can think of for this. I'm using Stripe, and I have the following Javascript to set it up:

```
$(function() {
  console.log("Stripe: ");
  console.log($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  issueOrder.setupForm();
});
```

When I directly access the page (i.e., put the exact URL in the address bar) where I make stripe orders, this works great. console.log logs what I'm testing, the stripe token is set up, and the payment goes through without a hitch.

However, when I access the page from a previously accessed page on the site (i.e., clicking a link to the payments page), nothing is logged and the stripe token is not set, leading to a server side error.

It seems like the javascript is being called once, but when a new page is rendered, somehow it recognizes that it has already been called, so it doesn't call the javascript again. Unfortunately, Stripe's publishable key isn't cached, so this leads to a server side error. Am I thinking about this correctly, and if so, how can I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Turbolinks - just override the turbolinks for the link that takes you to the page where you are using Stripe.

```
<a href="url" data-no-turbolink>Link Text</a>
```

or the Rails way

```
<%= link_to 'Link Text', url_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => true %>
```